How to exactly find the first matching zero in ARM using `shrn`, `fmov`, `rbit`, `clz`?
This blog talks about using ARM instructions that can make finding the first match faster. As much as I understand we use shrn, then fmov, rbit, clz and lsr since we do not have ctz in the ARM. I am not sure if my code correctly implements that logic.
I am trying to do:
I am trying to opimitize [>] loops in my Brainfuck programming language. [>] increments the pointer to find the cell that has the value 0. Instead of doing that one cell at a time I want to load 16 bytes at a time, find the first matching zero and update the index. If it is not found, I want to load the next 16 bytes, and so on.

First load the 16 bytes
if not found (cmp x1, #16 checks if the number of zeros are 64, 64 >> 2 = 16 so no zero found) load the next 16 bytes till found.).

I do not know if I am doing wrong and I have no idea what is the next step to look at? My exact question: Are the generated assembly code is correct? Am I using the registers and instructions correctly? Because there is little to none information about it, I had to look at the some patches
That is the an exmaple of the generated assembly code But I do not exactly how I can write a case and try if it finds the first matching zero. (The assembly code is generated from compiling the the brainfuck code [>]):
    .text
    .align 2
    .global _main
    .extern _putchar, _getchar, _malloc, _free, _memset
_main:
    stp x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    mov x29, sp
    stp x19, x20, [sp, #-16]!
    mov x0, #30000
    bl _malloc
    mov x19, x0
    mov x20, x0
    mov x1, x19
    eor w2, w2, w2
    mov x3, #30000
    bl _memset
loop_scan0:
    ld1.16b {v0}, [x19]
    cmeq.16b v1, v0, #0
    shrn v2.8b, v1.8h, #4
    fmov x4, d2
    rbit x4, x4
    clz x4, x4
    lsr x4, x4, #2
    mov x5, x4
    cmp x4, #16
    b.eq loop_scan2
    add x19, x19, x5
    b loop_scan1
loop_scan2:
    add x19, x19, #16
    b loop_scan0
loop_scan1:
    mov x0, x20
    bl _free
    ldp x19, x20, [sp], #16
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], #16
    eor w0, w0, w0
    ret

If this is correct how would I optimize [>>] or [>>>>] loops that moves the pointers to the right 2 and 4 times till to find a memory cell with value 0? Because Brainfuck benchmark has eamples that contain [>>>>] but not [>]; that is why, I am not sure if my implementation is correct.

But I do not exactly how I can write a case and try if it finds the first matching zero - by using different setup in front of the loop, that e.g. points x19 at some static data you emit with .byte..  With first-zero positions like 1, 15, exactly 16, more than 32, etc.  (And preferably with some later zeros as well as "decoys", although rbit/clz does implement ctz correctly.)

For the title question of how to find the first match, duplicate of Convert vector compare mask into bit mask in AArch64 SIMD or ARM NEON? - aqrit's answer cites the same blog you did, and shows working intrinsics code which maps directly to asm instructions (with vget_lane_u64 being fmov, and __builtin_ctz being rbit / clz).  Or you could even use a C compiler (e.g. on https://godbolt.org/) to see asm for one vector or for a loop calling it.  If you want this to be a debugging question about verifying your code, you need to test it.

As far as efficiency, you could avoid at least one b instruction, making the bottom of the loop a conditional branch.  You only need one way out of the loop (by finding a 0), so put that branch at the bottom, unless you also want to do any bounds-checking.  See Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)? re: rotating the loop and maybe peeling a couple instructions from the first or last iteration so the loop body can have a b.ne at the bottom.  Also, rbit/clz outside the loop, after finding a non-zero mask.

[>>>>] only checks every 4th cell, right? So AND to clear the bits you don't want to check after fmov. For power-of-2 numbers of > up to 16, the bitmask will be a repeating pattern like every other bit, every 4 bits, etc. for every 16-byte chunk. For 16 or more > increments between checks, SIMD can't help you unless you had strided or gather loads, so probably just do scalar.  (Or 32-byte vectors with SVE.)  For strides like 4 and 8, you might be able to shrn or something else with two separate compare results so you can bit-scan more compare results in one 64-bit integer.

eor w2, w2, w2 - AArch64 isn't x86, use mov w2, #0 or mov w2, wzr to zero a register.  eor-zeroing is required to have a false dependency on W2 (for memory_order_consume dependency-ordering semantics).  Most non-x86 ISAs are like that.  In x86 all loads are effectively acquire so no ISA rules about carrying data dependencies are necessary for software to take advantage of dependency-ordering.

I have successfully optimized memory scanning. I hope my code is clear: (For now I assume every brainfuck code is well-written):
                TokenType::MemoryScan(n) => { 
                    let loop_label = format!("loop_memory_scan{}", label_counter);
                    label_counter += 1;
                    // After the zeros in different indexes are found the following ands
                    // keep only the ones in the exact posiitions we want so rbit+clz find
                    // only the ones in the positions we want.
                    let constant = match *n {
                        // [>]: if reegister is zero (not found (no xf)) jump back.
                        1 => &format!("    cbz x8, {}\n", loop_label), 
                        // For [>>] since it moves pointer two times, keep the ones in even position: 0, 2, 4 ... 
                        2 => "    ands x8, x8, #0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f\n",
                        // For [>>>>] since it moves pointer four times, keep the ones in the positions divible by 4: 0, 4, 8, 12 
                        4 => "    ands x8, x8, #0x000f000f000f000f\n",
                        // The above logic is the same for [>>>>>>>>] as well.  
                        8 => "    ands x8, x8, #0x0000000f0000000f\n",  
                        _ => unreachable!(),
                    };
                    // Apply the finding the first matching logic
                    assembly.push_str(&format!("{}:\n", loop_label));  
                    assembly.push_str("    ld1.16b {v0}, [x19], #16\n");  
                    assembly.push_str("    cmeq.16b v0, v0, #0\n");        
                    assembly.push_str("    shrn.8b v0, v0, #4\n");
                    assembly.push_str("    fmov x8, d0\n");  
                    assembly.push_str(constant);  
                    if *n != 1 {
                        // If zero flag is set, it means ands found no matching 0s in the desires position
                        // So we simply jump to the loop again
                        assembly.push_str(&format!("    b.eq {}\n", loop_label));
                    }  
                    // Since we do not have ctz (count trailing zeros) in ARM we use rbit + clz (reverse and count leading zeros) instead
                    assembly.push_str("    rbit x9, x8\n");  
                    assembly.push_str("    clz x9, x9\n");  
                    // We have additional post increment +16. So we must decrement that firstly
                    assembly.push_str("    sub x19, x19, #16\n");  
                    // Divide by four and increment the pointer
                    assembly.push_str("    add x19, x19, x9, lsr #2\n"); 
                },                


You're still doing a lot of work inside the loop that could be before (setting up constants in register) or after (bit-scan to find the exact match position in a non-zero compare mask).  The loop condition could be fmov x8, d0 / ands x8, x8, #constant / b.ne  loop_label (where the constant is a mask of all-1s ([>]), 0x0F0F0F... for n=2, 0x00FF00FF... for n=4, or 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF... for n=8).  That clears any skipped bits so rbit/clz after the loop won't find them, only the one that matched.  (The n=1 case can actually just compare against 0, like cbz loop_label)

To simplify the pointer increment stuff so you only need one conditional branch and no b instructions, start with sub x19, x19, #16 before the loop and use an addressing-mode for the vector load that pre-increments by 16 with write-back to x19.  So the first iteration loads from the right place, and the loop condition runs with x19 still pointing to where the vector was loaded from.  Or post-increment and have the code after the loop compensate for the extra increment by 16.

@PeterCordes is there any way we could optimize [>>>>>>>>>] or any loop similar that increments the pointer by n where n is NOT power of two?

For length 3 or 6, for example, you could unroll by LCM(6, 16) = 24, so unroll by 3 vectors with 3 bitmasks in a register that (concatenated) form 8 repeats of the length-3 pattern.  Or in the general case, I think it might work to rotate the bitmask every iteration.  But it might need to be a 2-register rotate??  Not sure that works.

Or the other strategy (which is better for short search distances) is to use partially-overlapping loads.  They're often unaligned anyway.  For length 3, check all 16 positions in the vector, but then increment the pointer by 15.  (16 rounded down to a multiple of 3 is 15.  16 / 3 * 3, or I guess // if I'm remembering correctly that's how Python does integer division that rounds toward 0 or -Inf, either is fine.)  IIRC post-increment only works for multiples of the vector width so you'd need a separate add.
